# Rails STI has_many and belongs_to keep looking for type column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Installation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :original_lead, class_name: 'Lead'
end

class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :originated_installations, as: :original_lead, class_name: 'Installation'
end
```

Lead uses STI, having a type column.

That means I want each lead to have multiple installations.

The problem is when I try to do something like:

```
Lead.first.installations
```

It raises an error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column installations.original_lead_type 
does not exist LINE 1: ...WHERE "installations"."original_lead_id" = $1 AND
"installations"."original_lead_type" = $2
```

So, it is looking for an installation that belongs to a specific lead type, but I don't care about the lead type.

I was able to workaround that by replacing the has_many statement on the Lead model as follows:

```
has_many :originated_installations, inverse_of: :original_lead,
 foreign_key: :original_lead_id, class_name: 'Installation'
```

So, yes, my problem is solved, I just wanted to share and know if there is some other option I could have used instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing the has_many statement as follows solves the original problem:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :originated_installations, inverse_of: :original_lead,
 foreign_key: :original_lead_id, class_name: 'Installation'
end
```